# Any way to repair a cookie from an Oak tree that has cracked open?

Tags: wood-repair

I have a slice out of our Oak that has split. The power company had to take down because of interference with power lines. I have it since 2014 and would like to make it into a table. Is there any hope for this?

Comment: Edit a photo into your question, so we can actually see what you are talking about.

Comment: While you’re editing the pic in, please also tell us how thick the piece is, and what tools you have that could cut through it, plane it, and sand it.

Comment: How do you mean repair? If you want to close the crack, nope. You can of course fill it however, see the zillion epoxy projects in the woodworking community. Another viable option is to leave it and use as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, short version: epoxy the crack (thanks, @Graphus), or cut it at the crack, joint the edges, glue it together, and clean up the top.

If you wanted to come back with pictures and answers to the questions in the comments, you’d get more information.

Comment: i'll try to get a pic into this thread. thanks for suggesting that